# Pyspark : ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My data is in the following format after join

```
# (u'session_id', ((u'prod_id', u'user_id'), (u'prod_label', u'user_id')))
# (u'u'session_id', ((u'20133', u'129001032'), None))
# (u'u'session_id', ((u'2024574', u'61370212'), (u'Loc1', u'61370212')))
```

I want to treat the cases where the second tuple is None versus the one where it is not None. I tried filtering it using the following code, but I get error. How do I filter these out?

```
   left_outer_joined_no_null = left_outer_joined.filter(lambda (session_id, ((tuple1), (tuple2))): (tuple2) != None)
```

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

```
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine on my machine: Spark version is `1.5.1`.

I have tried like this:

```
left_outer_joined = sc.parallelize([(u'session_id', ((u'prod_id', u'user_id'), (u'prod_label', u'user_id'))),
                                (u'session_id', ((u'20133', u'129001032'), None)),
                                (u'session_id', ((u'2024574', u'61370212'), (u'Loc1', u'61370212')))])

left_outer_joined_no_null = left_outer_joined \
.filter(lambda (session_id, ((tuple1), (tuple2))): (tuple2) != None)

for value in left_outer_joined_no_null.collect():
   print(value)
```

Result is like as above this as you expected.

```
(u'session_id', ((u'prod_id', u'user_id'), (u'prod_label', u'user_id')))
(u'session_id', ((u'2024574', u'61370212'), (u'Loc1', u'61370212')))
```

**NOTE:**

In you input lines `(u'u'session_id` you have extra symbol `u'`. On the second and third lines it repeated two times. Maybe problem is there?